# Call unauthorized controller in Blazor scoped HttpClient

Tags: c#, blazor, dotnet-httpclient

So in Blazor Web Assembly (with ASP.NET Scoped) we have this great new HttpClient:

```cs
builder.Services.AddHttpClient(
    "ServerAPI", 
    client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress))
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

builder.Services
    .AddScoped(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient("ServerAPI"));
```

But I have some controller, that by design is supposed to be called before user authentication, thus I don't have token yet.

```cs
@inject HttpClient HttpClient;
// (... irrelevant razor code)
await HttpClient.PostAsync("UnauthorizedController", someData);
```

and I got exception:
`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.AccessTokenNotAvailableException`

And the question is, how should those unauthorized request be handled?

Comment: Use anonymous : https://www.syncfusion.com/faq/blazor/general/how-do-i-allow-anonymous-users-on-a-specific-blazor-page

Comment: nope - won't work. But thanks!

Comment: You are using a httpclientfactory add another client using a different name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to have only one `HttpClient` in your app.

Register 2 named clients:

```cs
builder.Services.AddHttpClient(
    "ServerAPI", 
    client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress))
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

builder.Services.AddHttpClient(
    "UnauthorizedServerAPI", 
    client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress));
```

In your `blazor component` inject `IHttpClientFactory` and create client when needed:

```cs
@inject IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory;
// (... irrelevant razor code)

var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("UnauthorizedServerAPI");
await client.PostAsync("UnauthorizedController", someData);
```

Comment: thank you! Did small change in your answer - client factory can be injected instead of HttpClient in this scenario

Comment: Ofc, I accepted it, pardon :)